# Is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \cos{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ indeterminate or zero at (0,0)?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, wolfram-alpha

I'd like to know what's the derivative of $f(x,y)=\cos{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ at $(0, 0)$.

WolframAlpha says [it is indeterminate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%20cos%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%29%20at%20%28x%2Cy%29%20%3D%20%280%2C0%29).

However, if we apply the definition, we can actually evaluate it to zero:

$$
f_x(0,0)
  = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f(h,0) - f(0,0)}{h}
  = \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{\cos{|h|}-1}{h}
  = \lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{\cos{h}-1}{h}
  = 0
\\
f_y(0,0)
  = \lim_{k\to 0} \dfrac{f(0,k) - f(0,0)}{k}
  = \lim_{k\to0} \dfrac{\cos{|k|}-1}{k}
  = \lim_{k\to0} \dfrac{\cos{k}-1}{k}
  = 0
$$

Aside question: if Wolfram is wrong, how often it happens in your experience? Does it ever happen?

Comment: The derivatives are both $0$, as you've correctly computed. Notice that WolframAlpha usually works with complex variables. For example, if you use it to evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} xe^{\sin x}$ it does a "mistake" saying it is indeterminate, while it is $\infty$ because $xe^{\sin x} \ge xe^{-1}$ for $x>0$. It says this because the sine is unbounded in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, this function is not only differentiable at $(0,0)$ (with the official definition), but in fact $C^1$. If one makes the standard mistake (which I've seen instructors make in teaching single-variable calculus) of blithely saying $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)$, it does work out nicely here. Note that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) &= \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \left(\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\left(-\sin\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right) \\ &= \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} -x\left(\frac{\sin\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right) = 0\cdot 1 = 0.
\end{align*}
Nothing whatsoever indeterminate. I think @Dunkelheit's comment is on point. Since I do not use Wolfram ordinarily to answer such questions, I had not previously bumped into this phenomenon.